# CRC ECMA-182 reference

Tags: c, ecma, crc64

I would like to cross check a C implementation of the CRC64 ECMA-182 algorithm.

I tried a different C code snippet I found online and I tried two online CRC calculators but each of them returned different results.

Is there some reference implementation or reference data that allows me to get a reliable reference checksum?

Comment: Seems like a reasonable question to me. Anyway, [here is the description of the ECMA-182 CRC](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/17plus.htm#crc.cat-bits.64), along with a check value of `0x6c40df5f0b497347` for the nine-byte string "123456789" (in ASCII, without the quotes).

Comment: Thanks. That is helpful. Do you have an idea why the CRC32C polynominal on that page is different to the one mentioned in https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3385 (0x1edc6f41 instead of 0x105EC76F1)?

Comment: They both have the same polynomial, which can be written with or without a leading one. I don't see 0x105EC76F1 anywhere.

Comment: Oh, you are right, I didn't see the hex polynominal and used the binary one which was in reversal order.

Answer (score 0):

The EMBL-EBI web site has an online checksum calculator, that is used in the context of bioinformatics for analysing protein or genome sequences:

http://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/so/seqcksum/

that supports many different methods, included the CRC64-ECMA-182. You can paste your input sequence directly in the form and it will return the checksum. The problem is that the input is a sequence must be one from a set of fixed formats:

http://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/so/seqcksum/help/index.html#sequence

However those formats are quite simple, for example the FASTA ([link](http://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blastcgihelp.shtml))